# True or False post rating system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We want to implement a system in our Rails app that allows users to rate posts as True or False. Upon user click of True, that will add one vote to the True count for that post. We want to set this system up so that if a user has already clicked True, but wants to switch to False, they can click False, and that vote will transfer over to the False column count, immediately on the client side.

How should we go about implementing something like this?

we currently have this in micropost.rb

```
belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :target_user, :class_name=>"User", :foreign_key=>"belongs_to_id" 
  has_many :ratings

def rateable_by_user?(user)
  self.ratings.where(:rater_id=>user.id).empty?
end
```

here is our current rating.rb

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :micropost_id, :owner_id, :rater_id, :rating
    belongs_to :micropost
    belongs_to :target_user, :class_name=>"User", :foreign_key=>"owner_id"
    belongs_to :user, :class_name=>"User", :foreign_key=>"rater_id"
    scope :trues, where("rating = ?", "true")
    scope :falses, where("rating = ?", "false")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea. Not sure why you have two belongs_to for the user model though (i realize there's two foreign keys, i just don't understand the reason for it). I think really this just comes down to creating a new rating object if the user doesn't have one for that post, setting the correct value based on which they click. If they do have an existing rating, simply swap the rating value.

```
 def switch_value
   self.rating = !self.rating
 end
```

If that's not what you're looking for, would you mind describing the particular aspect of the problem you are having trouble with?

Comment: i think were trying to get more at an AJAX style implementation. Where as one click upon False would set the user's rating false, but upon a click to True would simply switch it to True. Its almost hard for us to explain because the problem seems simple yet is really very complex.